# when using theme() in ggplot, receiving "Error: Only elements of the same class can be merged"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am building a simple plot with ggplot2. I usually have no issue with ggplot. But I'm running into the error mentioned in the title: "Error: Only elements of the same class can be merged"

Below is an example using a subset of the txhousing dataset in R, which looks a lot like the dataset that I'm using with a chr column (city in the txhousing example) and then several num columns (sales, volume, median, etc in the txhousing example). It pulls the same error:

```
txsamp <- subset(txhousing, city %in%
                 c("Houston", "Fort Worth", "San Antonio", "Dallas", "Austin"))


txs_plt <- ggplot(txsamp, aes(x = sales, y = median))+
  geom_point(aes(color = city), size = 4)+
  xlab("Sales")+
  ylab("Median")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(
    axis.title = element_text(size = 30),
    axis.ticks = element_text(size = 25))+
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "log10", labels = scientific)+
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10", labels = scientific)+
  scale_colour_viridis_d(name = "City", option = "plasma")

txs_plt
```

I've isolated the problem to the theme() function. If you comment out the theme() function, it works just fine. I use the theme() function all the time in a similar manner, so I'm uncertain of what is happening. The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67202689/getting-only-elements-of-the-same-class-can-be-merged-error-when-trying-to-use) was not useful and I'm having trouble finding mention of the error elsewhere.

I have ensured that my R version and ggplot2 package are up to date.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Try with `axis.ticks = element_line(size = 25)`.

Comment: That worked @stefan. I was reading that as axis.text rather than axis.ticks. That makes complete sense now. I knew it was a typo somewhere. Thank you for the quick reply.